# What caused this ext3 filesystem / mounting problem?

Tags: mount, ext3, kubuntu, hibernate

((K)Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.2.0-38-generic, fstype ext3)

I recently came across the 'great idea' of using hibernation to save state in my main OS, while I boot another OS.   I've done this without problems for the last few weeks.   A few days ago, my luck ran out ..

I resumed from hibernation into my main OS, used it all day (missing a couple warning signs - like being unable to save a file), and then realized that my root filesystem was mounted read-only; I tried remounting with no success, ran fsck, and rebooted.   Most things seem to have recovered OK (other than unsaved work (duh/not too big deal), and a Firefox problem), but obviously that's not something I'd like to repeat.   Dmesg and /var/log/ logs didn't tell me anything obvious (to my eyes) about what happened.   I didn't think to save the output from fsck.

Just to make things a little weirder - I actually physically removed the drive with the main OS (and swap/hibernate partition).   The secondary OS I was playing with is a 'live' OS.   So, the secondary never had direct access to the partition in question (or the hibernation image).

So, main question: What caused this?

// // //

**Edit:** for clarification, the above is the question, below was just my specualtion.   Per the comments, the RTC thing may be a red herring - it was just a guess.

My best guess of what happened is that perhaps the live OS changed my system clock, which then messed up my main/root ext3 fs (because .. timestamps?), causing an error, which forced a remount as ro.   (The root partition is normally mounted with the option "errors=remount-ro").   That said, at a user level, my desktop clock is not wrong/changed.   I didn't think to check more precisely (or at all) immediately after the 'problematic resume'.   Still, it's the only way I can think of for the secondary to break something *without having access to the primary*.

I think it had been a while since I ran fsck, but I'm not sure why that would crop up so abruptly.   But I guess that could be an explanation without any 'cross drive magic' - and would have nothing to do with my hibernation hijinks.

So, main question: What caused this?

Additional questions, if/as they fit: is the RTC thing plausible?   I'm pretty sure I've seen RTC related options in BIOS (to 'write-protect' it?) - is that a standard/consistent thing? (Or will some systems not be able to guard against RTC manipulation?)
What, if any, other non-volatile storage do I need to consider?

(That last one, especially, might need to be a seperate question, I guess.)

Comment: I think this is appropriate here.  If it should be on Superuser.SE instead, say so.  I mean, it's a filesystem question more than an OS-specific question, but it is a fs mostly used for U/L.   Alternately, it's a Linux hibernation question.   Also, not sure if I used the best tags, feel free to edit if you've got a better set.

Comment: You didn't mount it from the other OS? When you hibernate, all filesystems are still mounted (technically), so another OS touching any of those already-mounted filesystems, and then resuming the hibernated system, would inevitably lead to corruption. I've never heard of clock issues causing filesystem corruption; apart from files getting weird timestamps.

Comment: @frostschutz - No, I didn't mount it from the other OS. I can understand why that would be a problem; that (and protecting my hibernation-image) is why I physically removed the drive.  Which seemed like paranoid overkill, at the time.   What you say about the clock *not* being the culprit makes sense, and is good news (in a long term sense); it was just my only guess for how to screw up the fs without touching it directly.

Comment: Well, I don't have an answer for your question, then... with suspend to disk I sometimes get hangs on wakeup and the usual filesystem corruption you get from hangs or power losses in general, but nothing so unspecific. If you unplugged the drive, maybe a bad cable connection? But dmesg should've had some pointers then.

Comment: @frostschutz - Shouldn't be a physical connection issue. I removed and replaced the drive with the power fully off, and it's a laptop, so no cable.  And it ran all day, reading from the drive fine, and using swap (*presumably*, I didn't specifically check).  And, the drive is fine now.  Anything else?  Thanks for trying (and the point about clocks).